# require_once - connect wamp to server sql

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection, wamp

i have the following code that is supposed to send $distritos, $concelhos and $codigo_postal to mysql, unfortunately it is not working... Here is the code:

```
<?php

require_once "http://www.onemillionforonemillion.net84.net/conectar_a_base_de_dados.php";

echo "strings para ir para sql:<br>";

$distritos = "11 12 10 13 11 14 13 17 17 18 14 19 ... continuation";
$concelhos = "11 12 10 13 11 14 13 17 17 18 14 19 ... continuation";
$codigo_postal = "9980-039 9980-039 9980-034 9980-050 9980-060 9980-070 ... continuation";

print_r (explode(' ',$distritos));
print_r (explode(' ',$concelhos));
print_r (explode(' ',$codigo_postal));

$sql_distritos = (explode(' ',$distritos));
$sql_concelhos = (explode(' ',$concelhos));
$sql_codigos_postais = (explode(' ',$codigo_postal));

$c=0;
$d=1;
while($d < count($sql_distritos))
{
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO codigo_postal (codigo_distrito, codigo_concelho, codigo_postal)
VALUES('$sql_distritos[$c]','$sql_concelhos[$c]','$sql_codigos_postais[$d]')");
$c++;
$d++;
}

print_r ("<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>sql = " . $sql);

?>
```

I think the problem is the fact that i am using wamp, although the code connects to the server i cant get the information to be inserted into the database
Here is the database connection:

```
<?php

$db_host = "mysql3.000webhost.com";

$db_username = "a4875610_user";

$db_pass = "*********";

$db_name = "a4875610_db";

@mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("Could not establish a connection with the database!");
@mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("no database");

?>
```

Comment: You can't use `require` on code that's already been executed. You need to store it on the server where you have the php file trying to call it, and get to it by `C:\inetpub\www` rather than by http.

Comment: no, the code is executed only once using require_once

i just placed what is inside conectar_a_base_de_dados.php wich is the connection to the database as you can see

Comment: No, the code is executed on the remote server before you ever receive it, because you're calling it via HTTP. The Webserver on that machine has already executed the php and is giving you w/e that php script `echo`'d (which is probably nothing given the context how you're trying to use it), not the php code. As you can see, it doesn't work.

Comment: ok, i understand but i cant put this file in the server because it is to big - server limit is 2 mb - this file is to be executed only one time

Comment: Then it has to be accessed another way, such as SMB or FTP. HTTP will not work. (I'm not sure if FTP will work either, but it makes sense in my head)

Comment: can you show me an example of what to do ?

Comment: I cannot, I'm sorry. This is a very strange issue to have. If your limit is mico-sized like your 2mb, then you should find another way to do what you need to do from that piece of code. I assume this has to be for some sort of school project (who else limits at 2mb!?!?), so the teacher probably has it set to 2mb for a specific reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
require_once "http://www.onemillionforonemillion.net84.net/conectar_a_base_de_dados.php";
```

Will not work. PHP will parse that file on the server and return an empty file. So you will not have connection information included in your script.

Comment: put the connection file on your server and link to it locally: require_once "conectar_a_base_de_dados.php"; // this implies it is in the same dir as your file

Comment: the file is huge, and the server only allows 2 mb files

Comment: PHP scripts must be on disk, they cannot be read from URL. When Read from url they have been parsed. You can see this by going that url in your browser and look at the source.